# how SAML works between an IDP and a SP?

Tags: saml-2.0

After successful authentication,which is done by identity provider,How Secure Assertion Markup language 2.0 request is generated for that user and what does it contain?

Answer (score 0):

How the assertion is generated is up to the IDP. What it contains it ultimalty the IDPs decition too. 
In the [SAML Assertion spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf) you can read what it can contain. Chapter 2 has a good summary
To know specifically what your IDP provides you would have to talk to them.